# Is it correct to say "In the room lay a table"?

Tags: word-usage, phrase-usage, grammaticality

It seems that in stories people often put the adverbs of place at the beginning of the sentence as in

"*In the room lay a table*"

"*In the kingdom lived a king*"

Some Asian languages say that way.

**What is its grammar called?** I searched for "**Adverb Inversion**" but it didn't show the one I am looking for.

Comment: We say that a table (or other piece of furniture) _stands_ somewhere, it doesn't lie. _In the room stood a table_ is fine.

Comment: It's called subject-dependent inversion. In the first example, the subject _a table_ and the locative complement _in the room_ have inverted, putting the subject in final position where it typically gets greater phonological prominence than in its basic position. Similarly, in the second example the subject _a king_ and the locative complement _in the kingdom_ have inverted.

Comment: This would actually be a rather rare order for a language, though I'm sure there are some Asian languages with that order... not the "big" ones.  Putting the subject after the verb is unusual.

Comment: I wouldn't say it's rare. Subject-dependent inversion belongs in the 'information packaging' domain. A preposed complement, as in "in the room" is here, acts as a link to the preceding discourse, i.e. it is closely related to information previously introduced.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is called subject-verb inversion.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subject%E2%80%93verb_inversion_in_English#:%7E:text=Subject%E2%80%93verb%20inversion%20in%20English%20is%20a%20type%20of%20inversion,the%20bed%20stood%20a%20lamp.) has a similar example as yours.

> Subject–verb inversion in English is a type of inversion where the subject and verb (or chain of verbs, verb catena) switch their canonical order of appearance so that the subject follows the verb(s), e.g. A lamp stood beside the bed → **Beside the bed stood a lamp.** [emphasis added]

Comment: Actually, it's called 'subject-dependent inversion'. The subject _a table_ and its complement (i.e. a dependent) of the verb _in the room_ have switched sides of the verb, which has remained fixed in the middle.